# How can I add a Categories page link to a menu?

Tags: categories, menus, dashboard, woocommerce-offtopic

Not a link to a specific category, but a link to a page that lists all categories of a custom post type (WooCommerce Products).

Comment: Can't use the "links" one in the menu builder and add a direct url to the page you want?

Comment: How would I find the url for the product categories? Do I have to create an arbitrarily named page, or is there a standard url like there is for plain normal categories, `/category/uncategorized`?

Comment: I think if you want all products in a specific category this should work : shop/product-category/something/  but I am not sure about a page which lists all categories.

Comment: is this for the WooCommerce plugin, or for your own CPT called woocommerce with your own categories/taxonomies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce shows a listing of product categories at `/products`, which can be added to a menu as a simple link to that url. It took me a while to find that url.

To override the categories page template, grab a copy of `templates/content-product_cat.php` from the [WooCommerce repo](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce) and place it at `woocommerce/content-product_cat.php` in the child theme.